# How to make an object follow the end of another object that is following a curve?

Tags: modifiers, objects, bezier-curves, transforms, parent

How do I make an object that follows another object exactly like this but without the deformation issue?

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5bK9.jpg

(The curve can be manipulated using the empties through hook modifiers, the object with the deformation issue is not parented to anything. I used a curve modifier for the object with the deformation issue and it is tracking the curve shown, it is moved in a position so that it always follow the end of the tentacle and its rotation is correct)